# How to sent and get Response Of 01A6 (Odometer) PID with ELM327(OBD-II)

Tags: obd-ii, elm327

i want to get response of PID A6 of 01 Service (01A6 : Odometer) with ELM327(OBD-II), But the Response will be "7F 01 12" and this is not valid response.

example of my try:
[EXAMPLE SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwGaM.jpg)

Thank you for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NRC `0x12` means `subFunctionNotSupported`, i.e., your vehicle does not support this service.

Odometer reading PIDs are pretty recent additions to the standard, so most vehicles do not implement that.